# Alexa LWA SDK not work when my app target Android 14

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

The target SDK version has been reduced from 34 (Android14) to 33 (Android13) and compilation verification issues. It was found that the Amazon shopping app can be redirected normally. It can be determined that the target SDK version 34 (Android14) caused the failure to jump authorization.

I've integrated version 3.1.0 of the LWA (Login with Amazon) SDK into my app. Previously, on Android versions up to 13, the app could seamlessly redirect users to either a web browser or the Amazon Shopping app for authorization and login. However, I've recently discovered a critical issue on Android 14 devices. If the Amazon Shopping app is installed on these devices, the app fails to redirect for authorization.
Interestingly, once the Amazon Shopping app is uninstalled, the redirection to a web browser for authorization works flawlessly. This leads me to suspect that there might be a compatibility issue between the LWA SDK and the latest Android 14 system.
To further investigate, I tested with the latest LWA SDK version 3.1.2 available on the official website.
Unfortunately, the problem persists even with this updated version.
Below are the logs output by the LWA SDK when I replicated the issue. I hope they will be useful in solving the problem.
16:38:56.189 V requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
16:38:56.243 W Frame time is 0.245744 ms in the future! Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamns lising the correct timenase

The target SDK version has been reduced from 34 (Android14) to 33 (Android13) and compilation verification issues. It was found that the Amazon shopping app can be redirected normally. It can be determined that the target SDK version 34 (Android14) caused the failure to jump authorization.